# How can I see if there is a difference between two columns, if so, add a point to an aggregate column, then move on to the next two

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, statistics, aggregate

My dataframe has 1000 columns containing values between 0-4.

| City | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Newcastle | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Liverpool | 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| Cardiff | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| Glasgow | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |

Every time two columns are not equal, I want to add +1 to the Aggregate column.

| City | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Newcastle | 2 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| Liverpool | 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Cardiff | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| Glasgow | 0 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 |

I feel this could be seen as:

```
if df['Q1'] != df['Q2']:
    df['Aggregate'] + 1
else:
     pass
```

Then:

```
if df['Q2'] != df['Q3']:
    df['Aggregate'] + 1
else:
     pass
```

I would like this to iterate through all 1000 columns, so I can quantify how many changes each row has had overall.

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), no need for a loop in your case. You can try this :

```
qs = df.filter(like="Q") #or df.drop("City", axis=1)

df["Aggregate"] = qs.diff(axis=1).fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

        City  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Aggregate
0  Newcastle   2   3   3   0          2
1  Liverpool   4   2   1   4          3
2    Cardiff   2   2   2   3          1
3    Glasgow   0   1   3   1          3
```